# Threads throwing RuntimeException - Impact on Threadpool

Tags: java, threadpool

I just read [this article](http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Cancellation-and-Shutdown/Handling-Abnormal-Thread-Termination/) and thought that threadpool may run out of worker threads if the `Runnable`'s throw exception and exit. I did a small code and checked, but the poolsize didn't vary.

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadPoolExecutor tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.execute(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Executing & Throwing");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.execute(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Executing & Throwing");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.shutdown();
}
```

}

Output I got was

```
0
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at threads.ThreadPoolTest$1.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Executing & Throwing
1
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at threads.ThreadPoolTest$2.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Executing & Throwing
1
```

This is on Java 7. **Is there any java Threadpool implementation which is vulnerable as stated in the article?**

Comment: AFAIK when there is any RuntimeException in the worker thread that worker completes and some other worker takes its place, ThreadPoolExecutor spawns a new Worker to maintain the pool size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the article, the gist is that a poorly written thread pool can suffer from this problem. In fact, any application that creates a thread and doesn't/can't handle an uncaught exception from that thread.

I'd expect any reputable source of a thread pool to handle this scenario in some fashion. By reputable, I would include the Oracle-sourced solutions. I suspect if someone was hand-coding a thread pool and they lacked experience then they'd write a less-robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

The article states:

> The standard thread pools allow an uncaught task exception to terminate the pool thread

which is the case. A slightly amended version of your code shows that the ThreadPool will create a new thread when the previous has died due to an exception.

As a side comment, you would in general use the `submit` method, and try to `get` on the returned Future to see if an exception has be thrown.

Output:

```
0
Creating new thread
Executing & Throwing
Creating new thread
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication4.Test2$2.run(Test2.java:47)
    ....
1
Executing & Throwing
Creating new thread
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication4.Test2$3.run(Test2.java:56)
    ....
1
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadPoolExecutor tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1), new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            System.out.println("Creating new thread");
            return new Thread(r);
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Executing & Throwing");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Executing & Throwing");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println(tp.getPoolSize());
    tp.shutdown();
}
```